# QQmlPropertyCache: QQuickItem has FastProperty class info, but has not installed property accessors

Tags: arm, qml, qtwebkit, yocto, qt5.4

Built **Raspberry Pi 2** linux distro including Qt5.4 + QtWebKit + QML plugin using Yocto on `fido` branch [See tutorial](http://www.embarcados.com.br/raspberry-pi-2-qt5-yocto-parte-1/)

#### Testing with the following QML script

```
root@raspberrypi2:~# more webkit.qml
import QtWebKit 3.0

WebView {
    url: "http://www.nokia.com"
    preferredWidth: 490
    preferredHeight: 400
    scale: 0.5
    smooth: false
}
```

When running this script I am getting the following error:

```
root@raspberrypi2:~# /usr/bin/qt5/qmlscene --platform eglfs webkit.qml 
Unable to query physical screen size, defaulting to 100 dpi.
To override, set QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH and QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT (in millimeters).
QQmlPropertyCache: QQuickItem has FastProperty class info, but has not installed property accessors
Aborted
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution was to add the line

```
import QtQuick 2.0
```

to the QML file.